# Tensorflow 2 object detection api random crops of training images as training dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I need to train a network to detect traffic signs, using Tensorflow2 object detection API. However, a lot of the traffic signs instances contained in the training dataset are very small.
Most of the images in the training set have also a quite high resolution (there are a variety of resolutions), and I am currently resizing the images to 1024x1024. I am using a Faster R-CNN 101.
The resizement causes the road signs to become extremely small and the network is not able to detect them, I am using this scales for the anchors: [0.1, 0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 1.75].

I think there are two possible solutions:

- use the original images without resizing them (I think it requires a lot of memory on the GPU)
- random crop the training images and use the crops as training dataset, so that the traffic signs don't become too small

The second solution is a bit tricky because you also have to change the bounding boxes coordinates I guess. Is there a way to do that easily?

Furthermore, any other idea is well accepted.

Thanks.

Comment: I found a paper that uses the second approach you mentioned. I don't think that adjusting bounding box coordinates for the cropped images will be an issue since you know where the coordinates of the cropped images are relative to the original image. 
Here's the paper: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Vit_Ruzicka2/publication/327913243_Fast_and_accurate_object_detection_in_high_resolution_4K_and_8K_video_using_GPUs/links/5bbdf2fea6fdccf2978f11e8/Fast-and-accurate-object-detection-in-high-resolution-4K-and-8K-video-using-GPUs.pdf

Comment: Ok I will look at that, thanks.